# Coordinating messagebox or dialog location on multi-screen

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, modal-dialog, class-library

I have App1 with main form Form1(Winform). Form1 launches a non-modal form Form2. Form2 uses a class library CL1 that displays a modal dialog DL1.

Once Form2 is displayed and then DL1 is displayed, the location of DL1 is over Form2.

When Form2 is displayed, and then its location is changed via dragging it to a different screen, the DL1 displayed will be over the original position of Form2 (the position before dragging). I want to be able to coordinate the position of DL1 over Form2 even if its move.

I've done some research but no solid solution yet. I'm hoping to have a discussion around this issue here.

Basically DL1 needs its parent location. Since parent is a class library, DL1 is probably displayed by using some Windows algorithm I assume.

I tried saving location of Form2 on close and each location change. Hoping to use it when launching DL1. I think it may work but then you will have to register and maintain for each dialog or message box.

By the way, there may be App2 and App3 using CL1.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

oinBefore `ShowDialog()` is called on DL1 you need to its `StartPosition` property to `FormStartPosition.Manual`. Then DL1 will start wherever you specify its location.

For example

```
Form2 dlg = new Form2();
dlg.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
dlg.Location = this.Location;
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

This will start dlg as a modal dialog at the same location as the form calling the code.

Or overload the ShowDialog function in DL1 for example:

```
public void ShowDialog(Point start)
{
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = start;
    this.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: this.Location is not available as its a class library

Comment: I would suggest then that you overload the `ShowDialog()` method to include a start position like this
`public void ShowDialog(Point start)
{
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = start;
    this.ShowDialog();
}`